# INSERTED table not retrieving values inserted after truncating

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Trigger that makes changes to a columns value in a table if the value is updated/inserted.

If I do a direct UPDATE statement to the table the Trigger works.
If I run a stored procedure to truncate the table and repopulate the table (data warehouse table/ETL)the trigger does not work.

I am not sure why the trigger is not working after I run the stored procedure. Any ideas? Thank you ahead of time.

HERE is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
    ON PlanesTable
    AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @vPlaneID INT;

    SELECT @vPlaneID = INSERTED.PlaneID
    FROM INSERTED;

    UPDATE dwPlanesDim
    SET ServiceStatus = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, LastService,GETDATE())  <= 30 THEN 'Current' 
        ELSE 'Review Service'
        END
    WHERE @vPlaneID = PlaneID
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
GO
```

Comment: Does it work if you `UPDATE` after `TRUNCATE`?

Comment: Your trigger only fires on `UPDATE`. How about changing your trigger to `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`. And DO NOT assume that the `inserted` table contains only one row!

Comment: Note: `inserted` in the trigger is a table containing all inserted (updated) rows, but your trigger is designed to work on a single row. So unless you're updating a single row with each update, your trigger might not work as you expect it should. A better way of doing you trigger would be joining `dwplanesdim` with `inserted` on `dwplanesdim.planeid = inserted.planeid` rather than using a variable like you currently do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRUNCATE` is not an update. In fact technically, it's not even DML. `TRUNCATE` works so quickly specifically because it doesn't log any individual rows. It just deallocates the disk space used by the table. Consequently, those `inserted/deleted` tables are not available after a truncation.

Additionally, if you truncate the table and then populate the table, that will be an insert, not an update. Since this trigger is set only to fire after `UPDATE`, it won't fire in that case.

Comment: So I would need to change AFTER UPDATE to AFTER UPDATE, INSERT? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I've understood your use case correctly, I should think that would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Not firing any trigger is an expected outcome using a TRUNCATE.

Extract: TRUNCATE TABLE cannot activate a trigger because the operation does not log individual row deletions. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql